# If statement to distinguish which "Case" query should be added to select query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

I'm stacked on following query. I need to create an if statement or something similar to distinguish which "CASE" should be added to my select query.

`If page_type = 'Region' or 'City'`  add this to the query:

```
( CASE When landing_page like concat('%',path_id,'%') and
(LENGTH(landing_page) - LENGTH(REPLACE(landing_page, '/' ,'')) / LENGTH('/')) = 2
Then 'True' Else 'False' End as 'correct lp' , )
```

`Elseif page_type = 'Item'` add this to the query:

```
( CASE When landing_page like concat('%',path_id,'%') and
(LENGTH(landing_page) - LENGTH(REPLACE(landing_page, '/' ,'')) / LENGTH('/')) = 3
Then 'True' Else 'False' End as 'correct lp' , )
```

`Elseif page_type = 'POI (Alle)'` add this to the query:

```
( CASE When landing_page like concat('%',path_id,'%') and
(LENGTH(landing_page) - LENGTH(REPLACE(landing_page, '/' ,'')) / LENGTH('/')) = 3 and
'Hotel' NOT IN landing_page
Then 'True' Else 'False' End as 'correct lp' , )
```

---

Case queries should be added to the following query according to `if` outcome:

```
 SELECT
  MONTHNAME(k.crawl_date) As 'Month',
  YEAR(k.crawl_date) As 'Year',
  WEEKOFYEAR(k.crawl_date) As 'Week',
  k.landing_page,
  k.pos,
  CASE WHEN k.pos = 0 THEN 'No Rank' WHEN k.pos < 4 THEN 'Top 3' WHEN k.pos < 11 THEN 'Page 1'
       WHEN k.pos < 21 THEN 'Page 2' WHEN k.pos < 31 THEN 'Page 3' WHEN k.pos < 41 THEN 'Page 4'
       WHEN k.pos < 51 THEN 'Page 5' WHEN k.pos < 61 THEN 'Page 6' WHEN k.pos < 71 THEN 'Page 7'
       WHEN k.pos < 81 THEN 'Page 8' WHEN k.pos < 91 THEN 'Page 9' WHEN k.pos < 101 THEN 'Page 10'
       WHEN k.pos < 111 THEN 'Page 11' END as 'Page', 
 k.path_id,
 k.domain,
 x.keyword,
 x.engine_id,
 l.bucket,
 l.page_type,
 l.item_label
FROM
 xovi_stats k
 LEFT JOIN xovi_keywords x ON k.keyword_id = x.id
 LEFT JOIN xovi_labels l ON l.id = x.label_id
```

Comment: The `CASE` clause is to be added into the `SELECT` part, I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest `CASE` clauses like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (page_type IN ('Region', 'City')) THEN
            CASE
                WHEN landing_page LIKE ... THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END
        WHEN (page_type = 'Item') THEN
            CASE
                ...
            END
        WHEN (page_type = 'POI (Alle)') THEN
            CASE
                ...
            END
    END AS lp,
    MONTHNAME(k.crawl_date) As 'Month', -- other fields
    ...
```

Or you can also nest `IF()`, as you suggest:

```
SELECT
    IF ( (page_type IN ('Region', 'City')),
        -- if (page_type IN ('Region', 'City')) then
        CASE
            WHEN landing_page LIKE ... THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
        END,
        -- else
        IF ( (page_type = 'Item'),
            -- if (page_type = 'Item') then
            CASE
                ...
            END,
            -- else
            IF ( page_type = 'POI (Alle)',
                -- if (page_type = 'POI (Alle)') then
                CASE
                    ...
                END,
                -- else
                NULL
            )
        )
    ) AS lp,
    MONTHNAME(k.crawl_date) As 'Month', -- other fields
    ...
```

Off-topic notes:

- you can replace your two-branch `CASE` statements with simple `IF()`:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN landing_page LIKE ... THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
END AS alias ;

-- strictly equivalent to

SELECT IF(
    landing_page LIKE ...,
    'True',
    'False'
) AS alias ;
```

- you can replace your large existing `CASE` with:

```
CASE
    WHEN k.pos = 0 THEN 'No Rank'
    WHEN k.pos < 4 THEN 'Top 3'
    ELSE CONCAT('Page ', (k.pos -1) DIV 10 +1 )
END AS 'Page'
```